# Microsoft Excel formula or search?

Tags: software, ms-office

I have four Microsoft Excel workbooks (excel spreadsheets). One is a list of **Donors** and the other three are separate campaigns which had click-throughs from an email blast. What I've been asked to do is to find out which click-throughs actually donated to that campaign.

Hope this makes sense. I'd love some help on what to do...be it a macro or formula to tie together two workbooks, or perhaps there's a simpler solution I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can simple reference another workbook with by prefixing your formula with the filename in square brackets:

```
=[donors.xls]Sheet1!A5
```

and work with that.

If the files are not in the same directory, try to specify the path:

```
=/Users/somewhat/files/[donors.xls]Sheet1!A5
```

<sub>PS: That works for Excel on Windows. But I hope this works the same way for Office for Mac.</sub>